# Group emails as converstations using AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I am using AWS Lambda function and using AWS SES to send emails
I want my emails to be grouped in the inbox in the same way as if someone replies to normal emails.
Currently, if I am using send_email function. Even if email subjects are the same, still emails are seen as single and not part of conversation.

Comment: Maybe https://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/822/36.htm !?